# Why does app work on local host, but does not on github pages?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, github-pages

I built an app using React App, to create a monsters Rolodex website. it works fine on my localhost, however, after pushing it to GitHub pages it only shows title and search box. It's missing images and text.

my text editor is VS code, I am on windows pc.

the URL is https://jirehg.github.io/my-monsters-roladex/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` chnage this to `https`, and how does it looks in your local ?

Comment: ok where do I find that url? on my local host the page looks fine and as it should

Answer (score 1):

Try to push it via gh-pages.

1.add pachage as a dev-dependency via `npm install gh-pages --save-dev`
2.make sure you add to package.json:
`"homepage": "http://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}"`
3.make sure to add these scripts to package.json:
`"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`
4.Add it as a remote and `npm run deploy`

Comment: I used gh pages following the steps you mentioned. The last time I added a static page to gh, i uploaded the file, would that be a better option?